# imageio.ffmpeg.download() Requires a different install of imageio, and imageio won't install a different version

Tags: python, moviepy

I'd like to run VideoFileClip from moviepy.  I'm running Spyder through Anaconda.

When I do try to run it, I get the error:

> RuntimeError: imageio.ffmpeg.download() has been deprecated. Use 'pip install imageio-ffmpeg' instead.'

When I try `pip install imageio-ffmpeg`, I get:

> Requirement already satisfied: imageio-ffmpeg in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.3.0)

Other answers recommend `sudo pip install imageio==2.4.1`. I get the error:

```
moviepy 1.0.0 has requirement imageio<3.0,>=2.5; python_version >= "3.4", but you'll have imageio 2.4.1 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: imageio
  Found existing installation: imageio 2.5.0
Cannot uninstall 'imageio'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

If I try `conda remove imageio` I eventually get...

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:

  imageio-2.5.0-py37_0

  moviepy-0.2.3.5-py_0

  scikit-image-0.14.2-py37ha925a31_0
```

So I'm concerned that if I actually remove imageio and install v2.4.1, I'll auto-remove moviepy, and then when I eventually reinstall moviepy, it will bump my imageio up to 2.5 again, completing the circle of incompatibility.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

> pip install moviepy --ignore-installed

Answer (score 0):

That's caused by the update of `imageio`

Use this instead:

```
sudo pip3 install imageio==2.4.1
```